# read date only to text from datetime in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#-4.0

LinkButton lnk_edit = (LinkButton)sender;
        st = "select * from BloodDonation where BloodDonationID=" + lnk_edit.CommandArgument + "";

```
    dr = db.readall(st);
    if (dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        if (dr.Read() == true)
        {
            hidden.Value = dr["BloodDonationID"].ToString();
            txt_amt.Text = dr["DonationAmount"].ToString();
            txt_date.Text = dr["DonationDate"].ToString(); // 
            txt_desc.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
            txt_dnto.Text = dr["DontatedTo"].ToString();
            btn_save.Text = "Update";
            dr.Close();
        }
    }
```

txt_date.Text = dr["DonationDate"].ToString() // in this line would like to read only date from datetime to textbox can any body know this pls help........

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.ToShortDateString().  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx